# I updated my content on cloudfront but my domain name on route 53 is not serving updated content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a route53 domain name routing to cloudfront distribution,
my cloudfront distribution is serving up updated content but my domain name say example.com serves outdated content.

How to ensure that my domain name serves updated content???

PS - the I have s3 bucket containing my application hosted using cloudfront, earlier my cloudfront was serving outdated content , but I invalidated the cache. Now the cloudfront url serves the latest content but domain name remains outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the issue was I was expecting domain name to serve the latest content and not waiting for the ttl to expire , after waiting for about an hour, I was able to view the latest content.